# How to display values from checked rows of gridview in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

Hi I am developing the asp.net application with javascript. I have one gridview with checkbox for each row. I have one button below. On clicking upon that button I am displaying values of only checked rows. I am looping through each row of gridview. I am trying as below.

```
 var second = [];
        $('#<%= gdvRegretletter.ClientID %> input[type="CheckBox"]').each(function () {if($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") == true)
            second.push($(this).val());
        });
```

If there are three checked checkboxes in the gridview I will get three times on on alert. I want to display Name column values. May I get some idean on this or May i know where I am going wrong? Thank you all.

Comment: A word on using this construct: `$('#<%= gdvRegretletter.ClientID %>...')` It fails if you move the code to it's own JS file.  Use an anonymous css class: `<asp:GridView id="gdvRegretletter" class="gdvRegretletter" ...>` and alter jquery to `$('table.gdvRegretletter input[type='checkbox']:checked')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly get all checked entries like this

```
var second  = [];
$('#your_id :checked').each(function() {
       second.push($(this).val());
     });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I hope your_id will be my gridviewID.

Comment: be mindful of unintended consequence.  The above assumes a single checkbox per row.  If you add more checkboxes per row this code will return those as well. It's a good practice to be a specific as you can.